# postgresql domain check array values

Tags: arrays, postgresql, validation

I am moving from what I see as the simple world of MySQL/Maria to the more complex world of PostgreSQL. I am creating a fairly conventional table of a person's contact details. One of the columns is the telephone numbers, which should be an array. (It makes sense to do this rather than three tables, one for the contact, one for the telephone number and one joining the two.) I would like to ensure that every telephone number (defined as "text" - although comprised solely of digits a telephone number is not a number), contains only digits.

I cannot work out how to construct the CHECK clause either for the column definition or for domain specification. The domain would be defined as an array of "text" or "char".

Can anyone help?

Comment: "*It makes sense to do this*" - why? De-Normalizing usually does _not_ make sense. Plus: your check would be **very** simple if you _did_ normalize the model

Comment: The reason for not normalising, is that it isn't really a many-to-many relation. Generally a private individual does not share a phone number with anyone else.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons someone would share a number with other people: primarily, if they live together with a landline. People also call from work, where they don't even own the number. Numbers change owners over time, which doesn't cause many-to-many at a particular moment, but eventually has to be dealt with.

Comment: That is not the case here. Fully normalising the data is just not needed. Without wishing to be dogmatic or ungrateful, I am not prepared to accept any solution that requires nomalisation.

Comment: @Nicole You said `Fully normalising data is just not needed` but it gets you in trouble to handle them in that way since you need our help. **Problems with handle or using the structure is most of the time the best argument for model normalization.**

Comment: I am asking for help on syntax not on how to handle the data.

Comment: Collecting the telephone numbers into an array might be even worse than having three separate columns {home,work,mobile} Beside: maybe hstore could be of help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an excellent article that addresses my own question at
[merging-and-manipulating-arrays-in postgresql](http://tech.valgog.com/2010/05/merging-and-manipulating-arrays-in.html)